# How to change Eclipse enviornment

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I am using eclipse pdt and all my files in the folder have php support. I want to use javascript support on JS files. How could I do that in Eclipse pdt helio?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the project and select *Web Development Tools* > *Add JavaScript Support*